# Porting CDate(long) from VB6 to C#

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

I have been tasked with converting an old VB6 program to to C#. One function I have been having trouble porting over is the calculation of a birthdate from a filed that was read from a binary file:

```
.BirthDate = CDate((CLng(recPatient.birthDateByte2) * 256) +
                         (recPatient.birthDateByte1 + 366))
```

The only function I could find that is remotely similar is:

```
DateTime BirthDate = DateTime.ToDateTime((long)recPatient.birthDateByte2) * 256) 
                                       + (recPatient.birthDateByte1 + 366));
```

However `ToDateTime(long)` just returns an `InvalidCastException`.

Now I can build the string manually but I can not find any documentation anywhere on VB6's `CDate(long)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use

```
  DateTime.FromOADate((double)recPatient.birthDateByte2 * 256 
                     + recPatient.birthDateByte1 + 366)
```

instead.

[Here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/designer/Functions223.html) is a small piece of documentation about CDate(long). It is not from MS and not about VB6, but since CDate is part of all VBA implementations I have seen so far, I suspect it won't make a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

The old VB6 long data type becomes `System.Int32`, or simply int in C#

long in C# is `System.Int64`

double is `System.double`, which is a 64-bit floating point variable type